# DAC implementation in spartan 3e kit using verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl, spartan, dac

I have written two codes for implementation of DAC in Spartan 3E starter Kit, they seem to be working perfectly in simulation but when i attach them to chipscope and load on board I always get a zero value. I have also noticed that there were no critical warnings.
Code 1:

```
module dac_state_d(
input dacclk,
input reset,
input [31:0] dacdata,
output reg[31:0] previousdata,
output reg dac_mosi,
output reg dac_miso,
output reg dac_cs,
output reg dac_sck,
output reg dac_clr,
output reg spi_ss_b,
output reg sf_ce0,
output reg fpga_init_b,
output reg amp_cs,
output reg ad_conv,
output reg [2:0] state,
output reg ack
);

integer index=0;
parameter idle=3'b000, ready=3'b001, delay=3'b010, trans=3'b011, read=3'b100, increment=3'b101, check=3'b110;


initial begin//setting different registers on spi bus and initialization
    spi_ss_b='b1;
    amp_cs='b1;
    ad_conv='b0;
    sf_ce0='b1;
    fpga_init_b='b0;
end

always @(posedge dacclk or posedge reset) begin
    if (reset) begin
        index<=0; 
        dac_mosi<=0;
        dac_clr<=0;
        dac_sck<=0;
        dac_cs<=1;
    end
    else begin
        dac_clr<=1;
        case(state)
        idle: begin
                dac_sck <= 0;
                dac_cs <= 1;
                index <= 0;
                dac_mosi <= 0;
                ack <= 1;
                state <= ready;
              end

        ready: begin
                ack <= 0;
                dac_cs <= 0;
                dac_sck <= 0;
                dac_mosi <= dacdata[31-index];
                state <= delay;
               end

        delay: begin
                state <= trans;
               end

        trans: begin
                dac_sck <= 1;
                state <= read;                  
               end

        read: begin
                dac_sck <= 1;
                previousdata[31-index]<=dac_miso;
                state <= increment;
              end

        increment: begin
                dac_sck <= 1;
                index <= index + 1;
                state <= check;
                   end

        check: begin
                dac_sck <= 1;
                if (31-index < 0) begin
                    state <= idle; end
                else begin
                    state <= ready;
                end
               end  
        endcase
    end
end
endmodule
```

with its top module defined as

```
reg [31:0] dacdata;
wire [31:0] previousdata;
reg [3:0] command, address;
wire dac_miso_w;

assign dac_miso_w=dac_miso;
wire dacclk;

DACCLK clock(.clk(clk),
             .dacclk(dacclk)
            );

dac_state_d daq_run(.dacclk(dacclk),
                .reset(reset),
                .dacdata(dacdata),
                .previousdata(previousdata),
                .dac_mosi(dac_mosi),
                .dac_miso(dac_miso_w),
                .dac_clr(dac_clr),
                .dac_cs(dac_cs),
                .spi_ss_b(spi_ss_b),
                .sf_ce0(sf_ce0),
                .fpga_init_b(fpga_init_b),
                .amp_cs(amp_cs),
                .ad_conv(ad_conv),
                .dac_sck(dac_sck),
                .state(state),
                .ack(ack)
                );

initial begin
    command<=4'b0011;
    address<=4'b1111;
end

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (ack) begin
        dacdata[31:24]<=8'b00000000;
        dacdata[23:20]<=command;
        dacdata[19:16]<=address;
        dacdata[15:4]<=data;
        dacdata[3:0]<=4'b0000;
        pre_data<=previousdata[15:4];
    end
    else begin dacdata<=0; end
end 


//chipscope-------------------
wire[11:0] D;
wire R;
wire[35:0] CONTROL;
assign D=data;
assign R=reset;

ICON cs_con(.CONTROL0(CONTROL)); //INOUT BUS [35:0]
VIO cs_vio (.CONTROL(CONTROL), // INOUT BUS [35:0]
            .ASYNC_IN({pre_data,state,ack}), // IN BUS [12:0]
            .ASYNC_OUT({D,R}) // OUT BUS [12:0]
);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

endmodule
```

obviously top module has also I/O port description.

Code 2:

```
wire dacclk;

DACCLK clock(.clk(clk),
         .dacclk(dacclk)
        );

initial begin//setting different registers on spi bus and initialization
spi_ss_b='b1;
amp_cs='b1;
ad_conv='b0;
fpga_init_b='b0;
dac_clr=1;
dac_cs=1;
dacstate<=0;
//StrataFLASH must be disabled to prevent it driving the SDI line with its D0 output
//or conflicting with the LCD display 

strataflash_oe <= 1;
strataflash_ce <= 1;
strataflash_we <= 1;
end

always@(posedge dacclk) begin
                case (dacstate)
//------------------------------Bit 31 to 24 Don't Care----------------------------------
            0: begin//idle and allotment cycle(31-->x)
                    ack=0;
                    dac_cs=0;
                    dac_sck=0;
                    dacstate=1;
                end
            1: begin//read write cycle (31)
                    dac_sck=1;
                    dacstate=2;
                end
            2: begin//idle and allotment cycle(30-->x)
                    dacstate=3;
                    dac_sck=0;
                end
            3: begin//read write cycle(30)
                    dac_sck=1;
                    dacstate=4;
                      .....

                62: begin//idle and allotment cycle(0-->x)
                    dac_sck=0;
                    dacstate=63;
                end
            63: begin//read write cycle(0)
                    dac_sck=1;
                    dacstate=64;
                end     
            64: begin//Acknowledging completion of data transfer to DAC
                    dac_cs=1;
                    ack=1;
                    dacstate=65;
                end
            65: begin if (reset) begin dacstate=0; end
                       else begin dacstate=65; end end//idle or reset
            default: begin dacstate=0; end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

UCF file i used is as follows

```
NET "clk" PERIOD = 20.0ns HIGH 50%;
NET "clk" LOC = "C9" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL;

NET"dac_miso" LOC= "N10" | IOSTANDARD= LVCMOS33 ;
NET"dac_mosi" LOC= "T4" | IOSTANDARD= LVCMOS33 | SLEW= SLOW | DRIVE= 8 ;
NET"dac_sck" LOC= "U16" | IOSTANDARD= LVCMOS33 | SLEW= SLOW | DRIVE= 8 ;
NET"dac_cs" LOC= "N8" | IOSTANDARD= LVCMOS33 | SLEW= SLOW | DRIVE= 8 ;
NET"dac_clr" LOC= "P8" | IOSTANDARD= LVCMOS33 | SLEW= SLOW | DRIVE= 8 ;

NET "fpga_init_b" LOC = "T3" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 4 ;
NET "ad_conv"  LOC = "P11" | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 6 ;
NET "amp_cs"  LOC = "N7"  | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | SLEW = SLOW |DRIVE = 6 ;
NET "spi_ss_b"  LOC = "U3"  | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33  | SLEW = SLOW  | DRIVE = 6 ;
NET "sf_ce0" LOC = "D16" | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | SLEW = SLOW | DRIVE = 2;

NET "reset" LOC = "V4"  | IOSTANDARD = LVTTL | PULLDOWN;
```

I don't expect some-one to solve my problem but I feel helpless as i am debugging these codes from past 2 weeks and i am unable to find any problem. It will be really helpful if someone can point me towards error. I also went through some sample codes but as all are written in VHDL hence they were not great help to me. still i tried to match the logic and found it to be the same.

Comment: Are you sure you require Intial ... begin block? Cant you intialize your reg on reset? Are you giving proper reset period?

Comment: @PrakashDarji Yes Initial block is not required but it is not creating any problem either.

Answer (score 0):

The error in code is very basic, actually in connection to VIO. Inputs can't be connected to VIO as VIO is internal hence need to connect the wire only. Also, there is assignment of input to wire and Wire is reassigned by VIO, which is not acceptable.